# Storing relations space efficiently?

Tags: data-structures, succinct-data-structures

Let $f$ be a binary relation defined on set $S$, which contains numbers from $1$ to $n$. It is also given that number of $|\text{Img}(f)| \le k$. I want to store the function $f$ such in way such that space required is minimum.

I am trying to store the function with a graph, but number of edges turnout to quadratic in $n$.

**Question :**  How to store the relation $f$ space efficiently?

Comment: "functions" and "binary relations" are used in interchangeably in the question, which is confusing or just incorrect. While a function can be seen as a special type of binary relation, these two concepts are different. Please update your question to clarify, for example, you are only interested in binary relations. Or state your question in two parts, one for binary relations and one for functions.

Comment: Can you give an example of $f$?

Comment: @ orlp Let $S={1,2,3}$ and let $R=S \times S$ and for simplicity assume all elements of $R$ are mapped to element 1, which means $k$ is equal to 1.